# How can I verify that correct page is open in safari after clicking on iOS Native app link

Tags: automation, native, webdriver-io, appium-ios

I am using Appium with Webdriveio and testing Native app where I have a scenario to click on a button within the Native app that opens a link in the Safari browser.
As I am testing a native app I do not have the privilege to get in deep link from the dev tool so need to fetch the URL from safari browser to verify that the correct link is open

Is there any way to fetch Safari URL via Appium/Webdriveio within Native automation?